# Call Javascript Function within a <td> Element

Tags: javascript, angular, function, ionic-framework, html-table

I created a HTML table with multible table rows and multible columns. In the first row are text input fields to search the data below. 
When the user enter a value a search function should be called, but the event is never triggert. 
If I put the input field, with the same syntax, outside the table tags the function is triggert like expected.
The function below is not the search function. Its just a test function to check if the event is triggert.

HTML:

```
 <table id="result1" style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: auto;">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>
      <input (input)="test_2()" type="text" id="searchbar_2">          
    </td>
```

JS:

```
test_2(){
 let input_2 = String($('#searchbar_2').val());
 console.log("2: " + input_2);
}
```

Comment: Try changing to onkeyup="test_2()" instead of (input)="test_2()".

Comment: first what you are doing is wrong way of using angular, don't use jquery to access the value there,    you can just use `<input #search (change)="test_2(search)" type="text" id="searchbar_2">`  then `search` passed  will have the value 
  to access it use `search.value`. `(change)` event bound to classical input change event.

Comment: check abou input, output https://angular.io/api/core/Input on events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngModel`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query" (ngModelChange)="onSearch()">
```

And in your component controller:

```
export class YourComponent {

  query: string;

  onSearch() {
    // your search using this.query
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgdxbl

Comment: the event is still not triggert when using this syntax **HTML:** `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query" (ngModelChange)="onSearch(query)">`  **JS:**`query: string; onSearch(){console.log("2: " + this.query);}`

Comment: @TheMrGack See it working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgdxbl

Comment: tried it on a seperate page and it worked. but on my page it doesn't. maybe its a problem with the dynamic generated contend or the construction of the html table

Comment: @TheMrGack Yes, of course you cannot simply add elements to the DOM and hope that angular components will be loaded. That does not work. Forget your jquery stuff and do it the angular way. If you really want to load comüponents dynamically you'll use `ComponentFactoryResolver`. But I'm pretty sure, that you don't need this in your case. It's probably easily done with ngFor or whatever.

Comment: changed the syntax of the table and now its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td><input type="text" (click)="onClickMe()"></td>
```

and in your component

```
 onClickMe() {
    console.log('cliked');
  }
```

Check this example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ks4okw